# Store and extract JSX elements from localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, jsx

Within my React application, I store a javascript object in the localStorage. This object represents the theme used in the app. The problem is that one of the components of this object is a `JSX` element:

```
{
  ...
  icon: <Logo />,
  ...
}
```

I then use this object all over my app:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <>
      {theme.icon}
    </>
  )
}
```

The problem now is when I save this object in localStorage using `JSON.stringify()`, the JSX object is 'broken' and is no longer considered a React object after using `JSON.parse()`.

If I look to the localStorage, the `icon` element is stored like this:

```
{key: null, ref: null, props: {width: "154", height: "79", viewBox: "0 0 154 79"}, _owner: null,…}
```

So have you an idea of I can store, extract and then use a JSX element from localStorage?

Comment: instead of storing the component, store in a key and chose the proper component to be used based on the key, 

I'd recommend you to look into the context API if you're planning on using this icon throughout your app inside of multiple other components,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not change the icon value to string that reference which type of icon you want.

Example:

the object stored in localStorage :

```
{
  ...
  icon: "logo",
  ...
}
```

and in your code just make a condition :

```
render() {
  return (
    <>
      {theme.icon === 'logo'? <Logo /> : null}
    </>
  )
}
```

or make an Icon generic component that takes the type of icon as a prop and render the correct one :

```
render() {
  return (
    <Icon type={theme.icon}/>
  );
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, thanks for your try to answer posts. I leave an upvote to your post and I hope it helps to motivate you to keep going on Stack overflow

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't store react component references inside a string and JSON.stringify cannot serialize them properly (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

I recommend you replace the component with its name (or some key) which you will use then to render the appropriate component:

```
{
  ...
  icon: 'Logo', // then render the appropriate component based on this
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, it was an option, except that my conditions are much more specific than just the type of the component. So working with only `JSX` objects would have made things easier. But if there's no clean and simple way to do this, I'm going to go for something more conventional.